# Webdings are different on V10 vs V9. Why?

Tags: bugs, fonts

**Bug introduced in 10.0 or earlier and persisting through 10.2 or later**

---

I use FontFamily->"Webdings" in interfaces in several places, but among other things for custom opener icons, for example I use the following "icons" for open and closed openers:

[image]

In version 10 this is what happens:

[image]

Both screen grabs are taken on the same computer. Webdings is installed. I open V9 and evaluate and take a grab. I close V9 and open V10 and do the same.

I knew the Mathematica fonts were different in V10 compared to V9 but I don't understand why Webdings would be being rendered differently. I've tested a hand full of other fonts, including Wingdings, and have not observed any difference between V9 and V10. Can anyone enlighten me why Webdings is now different?

I'm on OS X 10.9.4 but my interfaces have worked on both Windows and Mac with V9.

**Edit**

I always use OS X. On my current machine I am running OS X 10.9.4. I have V8, V9, and V10 installed. None of these have a `/SystemFiles/CharacterEncodings/Webdings.m`

Regarding the error message that @m_goldberg gets when using `FromCharacterCode`. The same message occurs in V8 and V9 so I think that is irrelevant to the present issue.

V8

[image]

V9

[image]

So the same error message occurs for `FromCharacterCode` in previous versions but it clearly has no bearing on the using of `Style[6,FontFamily->"Webdings"]`.

The present issue is that you could use Webdings as a font in V8 and V9 on OS X and now you can't.

Comment: I see the correct glyphs as shown (first image) in V10 under Windows.  I presume you have an actual font with the name `Webdings` installed?

Comment: I get the correct rendering too in V10. I'm on Windows 8.1

Comment: I'm running on OS X and it appears that a needed file `/Applications/Mathematica.10.app/SystemFiles/CharacterEncodings/Webdings.m` is not installed in V10.

Comment: @m_goldberg What is (was) the content of that file in other versions?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard the font is installed. If It wasn't I'd never have been able to use it with V8 and V9 the past 4 years.

Comment: @m_goldberg that file is not present in V8, V9, V10 on my installation. What makes you think it is needed in V10?

Comment: @Mike Let me be more specific regarding what I was thinking: I know that some software can load fonts that are not installed in the OS proper; Adobe Photoshop is one example.  I thought perhaps past versions were loading Webdings from /SystemFiles while v10 relied on an OS copy.  Guess not.  I've got nothing else to suggest, other than it seems to be one of many localized bugs in v10. :-/

Comment: Because of what I need to do to access ZapfDingbats in V10. See my answer.

Comment: @m_goldberg ok, but see my edit. that is not the cause of the present issue.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard yep, 10.0.1 can't come quick enough

Comment: Yes, you can't access Webdings in V10. `Style` or something it calls must have changed. The option `FontFamily` no longer has any effect for that font in `Style`. I seem to recall that there is "better" integration of Unicode in V10. I suspect that may at the root.

Comment: A side note: Unicode is supposed to supersede Webdings. For specific glyphs you need there are #25B8 and #25BE, correspondingly `\[RightPointer]` and `\[DownPointer]` in Mathematica.

Comment: @kirma I don't like the way the whitespace is (particular above and below) around those glyphs compared to Webdings. That was why I chose Webdings over them a few years ago. Bottom line is I don't like those glyphs in my layouts and will go down another path rather than switch to them.

Comment: under Linux I got two empty square boxes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wolfram has confirmed this is a bug

Answer (score 3):

I'm running of OS X, and if I try

```
 Style[FromCharacterCode[6, "Webdings"], 24]
```

I get

> Get::noopen: "Cannot open /Applications/Mathematica.10.app/SystemFiles/CharacterEncodings/Webdings.m. >>"

On the other hand

```
Style[FromCharacterCode[Range[33, 255], "ZapfDingbats"], 24]
```

gives

[image: font-dump]

So it appears that the Webdings font is not supported in V10. A hint that this was true was given when I typed "Webdings" into the above code -- no completion was offered for it. On the other hand, completion was offered for the supported 
ZapfDingbats font.

Another verification

```
 MemberQ[$CharacterEncodings, "Webdings"]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

```
MemberQ[$CharacterEncodings, "ZapfDingbats"]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: If you repeat these tests with V9 and V8 you will see that this is not the issue here.

Comment: I thought your question was about how things work in V10.

Comment: the question is about why it works in 9 but not in 10. If you repeat the tests in your answer with V8 and V9 you get the same output as with V10 when testing `FromCharacterCode`. V8, V9, V10 produce the same output. However my question shows that when using FontFamily the breakage is only in V10. Hence this answer does not address why it does not work in V10.

Comment: You're right, I can't explain why. Perhaps you should ask WRI on Wolfram Community.

Comment: I've sent an email to tech support 1 minute ago!